# What to use in "traditional" awks (e.g. nawk) instead of interval expressions?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, gawk

I have next expression which works fine with gawk:

```
sub(/-[0-9]{1,2}/, final_rssi, macs[$4]);
```

It replaces 1 or 2 digits after '-' in array which contains string with new number .

Like -35dB could be replaced with -5dB etc.

But I need to use something instead interval expressions because I have restricted version of awk from Busybox v1.19.4 which is equivalent to gawk -c

Any ideas of how people did it before inventing interval expressions would be great.

Comment: `-c` (aka `--traditional`) and `--posix` are quite different. RE intervals are POSIX but they are not part of "traditional" awk (e.g. old awk, BWK awk, and `nawk`). I edited your question to correct any confusion between the 2.

Comment: Here is the awk which I use:
# awk --version
awk: unrecognized option `--version'
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2014-05-31 16:56:33 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: awk [OPTIONS] [AWK_PROGRAM] [FILE]...

 -v VAR=VAL Set variable
 -F SEP  Use SEP as field separator
 -f FILE  Read program from FILE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one or two matches of a digit, you can just use `/-[0-9][0-9]?/`.

The `?` means *zero or one occurrence*.

Testing it out:

```
$ gawk -c 'BEGIN{a="-35dB";sub(/-[0-9][0-9]?/,"-5",a);print a}'
-5dB
```

Answer (score 1):

The command *does* work in *posix mode*, you can always try it using `--posix`:

```
awk --posix '/-[0-9]{1,2}/' <<< '-12' # prints -12
```

Note that `-c` means *traditional* mode, which is identical to Brian Kerningham's `awk` from 1977. I doubt that you really want that, except for educational reasons.

Comment: [Section 9.4.6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06) documents the use of `{m,n}` in POSIX extended regular expressions.

Comment: I need it to work with awk which is part of busybox on openwrt AP. It is the same as -c in gawk. So believe me - If I say it doesn't work  - it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestions about posix.

Comment: The OP was confused. He is not using a POSIX awk, he is using a "traditional" awk, most likely `nawk`. Traditional does not means identical to old, broken awk from 1977 either btw, it means (essentially) compatible with nawk from 1985.

Comment: @EdMorton I was born in 1977 :) ... I just read trough the wikipedia page and found a POSIX version which was released in 1985.. That's why I though that the OP *really* means the 1977 version. However, seems like the POSIX standard has been further developed since then. Nowadays the `{x,y}` expression is part of the basic POSIX regulare expression standard. *traditional* seems to mean POSIX85. Thanks for making this clear for me!

Comment: Cool! :) (nothing more to say, expect that I would really like to do that once, just for fun)